# Python if statement output error

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x, while-loop

```
l=['hello','world']
first=l[0]
second=l[1]
d=len(first); 
x=0
while d>=0:
    e=len(second)-1
    while e>=0:
        if first[d-1]==second[e]:
            x+=1
        else:
            e-=1
    d-=1
if x>0:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

I am working on python 3. The above code should print YES as output but it isn't and rather program keeps on running indefinitely. I am new to python. Is there something I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your while loop to

```
while e>=0:
    if first[d-1]==second[e]:
        x+=1
    e-=1
```

Reason for the same is, say first[d-1] = 'a' and second[e] also = 'a' then it will never decrement value of e and you while condition e>=0 will satify and it will again goto if condition as d hasn't changed nor the e variable and hence lead to infinite loop.